# How to filter data, stored in jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, filter

I have a javascript variable to cache selector like:

```
var listOfDefferedElements = $('div [id^="Defer"]');
```

In debugg view, I see that the list has data similar to below:

```
listOfDefferedElements =
[
  <div id=​"DeferRed-1" class=​"Red Defer" title=​"Defer">​&nbsp;​</div>, 
  <div id=​"DeferGreen-3" class=​"Green Defer" title=​"Deffered">​&nbsp;​</div>, 
  <div id=​"DeferGreen-4" class=​"Green Defer" title=​"Defer">​&nbsp;​</div>​, 
  <div id=​"DeferBlue-6" class=​"Blue Defer" title=​"Defer">​&nbsp;​</div>​,
  <div id=​"DeferBlue-7" class=​"Blue Defer" title=​"Defer">​&nbsp;​</div>​, 
  <div id=​"DeferBlue-8" class=​"BlueDefer" title=​"Deffered">​&nbsp;​</div>, 
  <div id=​"DeferBlue-9" class=​"Blue Defer" title=​"Defer">​&nbsp;​</div>​
]
```

I would like to know how can I further filter this by class using a variable that stores the filter criteria

```
var filter = "Blue"
```

Need a output like this in a variable and finally I should be able to change the class 'Defer' -> 'Delete'. Appreciate any help.

```
listOfFilteredElements =
[
 <div id=​"DeferBlue-6" class=​"Blue Defer" title=​"Defer">​&nbsp;​</div>​,
 <div id=​"DeferBlue-7" class=​"Blue Defer" title=​"Defer">​&nbsp;​</div>​, 
 <div id=​"DeferBlue-8" class=​"Blue Defer" title=​"Deffered">​&nbsp;​</div>, 
 <div id=​"DeferBlue-9" class=​"Blue Defer" title=​"Defer">​&nbsp;​</div>​
]
```

Till now I tried this, it filters selectors that contain class 'Blue':

```
var listOfFilteredElements  = _.filter(listOfDefferedElements, function(elem){
    return (elem.className).indexOf('Blue') >= 0;
});
```

now can I have one statement to change/update the class for all elements inside it?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using classes for the colors, but an attribute like `data-color`.  What have you tried to do?

Comment: I know we should tell what we tried. I tried couple of ways but nothing seems to be correct. I searched but didn't find much help except people say to use grep but not sure if it will work.

Comment: Also, actually I have simplified the example by using color blue for class. But, I agree and keep in mind that I don't use classes for the colors.

Comment: What do you use for the colors then?

Comment: Actually I have a jQuery grid showing statuses in three column. Defer, Add and Delete (much like checkboxes but we have colored images). I am trying to cache the data (selectors) on page load for performance and then when user clicks on the select all checkbox on top of each column. I need to change the image to different image.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("div[id^="Defer"]." + filter).removeClass('Defer').addClass('Delete');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/GvyAg/

Since the jQuery method takes a string as an argument for selectors, you can concatenate to it like a normal string.  `.` is the class selector.

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills for the jsFiddle. This works great and I was also able to do the same. It would sound stupid but when the selector is in a variable, I was not sure how to filter it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('listOfDefferedElements ').find('.blue');
```

or as ExplosionPills said about data-* use those.

like this

Markup :

```
<div id=​"DeferBlue-6" class=​"Defer" title=​"Defer" data-color="blue">​&nbsp;​</div>​,
```

Jquery

```
var filterResult=$('div [data-color="blue"]');
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi for the response but .find on the class doesn't seem to work for me for some reason. It didn't return anything.